# Removing hard drive mounted to /home

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, migration

I have a mini home server running Debian 8.7 that during the initial installation had a 1tb hard drive mounted to / and a 60gb ssd mounted to /home. I would now like to remove the ssd for use in another project but am at a loss for how exactly to do so. I would like to have my home folder which has a bit of stuff from one account in it essentially migrated over to the 1tb drive.

My fstab currently reads.

```
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=1159719b-3f5b-482a-99c1-4dd05e9c1cc7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e39ea57f-7d07-4e53-8f2a-1571b23d06fe /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=2ff79462-458d-429f-9b56-8bb6540ffa32 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sda is the 60gb drive and sdb is the 1tb.

Is this easy to do? or would I be better backing up and setting everything up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (change `<editor>` to you text editor of choice):

```
sudo cp -Rp /home /home-copy
sudo <editor> /etc/fstab
```

In the editor, change:

```
UUID=e39ea57f-7d07-4e53-8f2a-1571b23d06fe /home  ext4  defaults
```

To

```
# UUID=e39ea57f-7d07-4e53-8f2a-1571b23d06fe /home  ext4  defaults
```

Then:

```
sudo mv /home /home-old
sudo mv /home-copy /home
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Remove the drive and reboot.